# Custom post type rewrite with_front

Tags: custom-post-types, rewrite-rules

What I'm setting up, I thought would be quite simple. In fact, I'm sort of amazed that the answer didn't just pop up after a half hour of searching here.

Here is the code to create my CPT:

```
register_post_type('headline', array(
'labels'                => array(
    'name'                  => 'Headlines',
    'singular_name'         => 'Headline',
    'add_new'               => 'Add Headline',
    'add_new_item'          => 'Add Headline',
    'edit_item'             => 'Edit Headline',
    'new_item'              => 'New Headline',
    'all_items'             => 'All Headlines',
    'view_item'             => 'View Headline',
    'search_items'          => 'Search Headlines',
    'not_found'             =>  'No matching headlines found',
    'not_found_in_trash'    => 'No matching headlines found in Trash', 
    'parent_item_colon'     => '',
    'menu_name'             => 'Headlines'
    ),
'description'           => 'Headlines from around the world.',
'public'                => true,
'supports'              => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'trackbacks', 'comments', 'revisions'),
'taxonomies'            => array('category', 'post_tag'),
'register_meta_box_cb'  => 'DfePostTypesHeadline::add_meta_boxes',
'has_archive'           => true,
'rewrite'               => array(
    'with_front'    => false
),
'can_export'            => true
));
```

The problem is the "with_front" call. Or rather, with the rewrite rules themselves. I've got my `flush_rewrite_rules()` call happening on plugin activation/deactivation. And I can see that the .htaccess file *is* getting rewritten, so it's working. But WordPress still cannot recognize my new permalink structure.

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but my register_post_type call is happening on the "init" hook. I'm wondering if a different hook is necessary?

```
/* Giddyup */
public function DFEPostTypes() {
    add_action( 'init', 'DFEPostTypes::register_content_types' );
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'DFEPostTypes::admin_pages' );
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'DFEPostTypes::admin_scripts' );
    add_filter( 'template_include', 'DFEPostTypes::template' );
    // Flush rewrite rules:
    register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'DFEPostTypes::flush_rewrite' );
    register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'DFEPostTypes::flush_rewrite' );
}
```

`register_content_types()` is the function that handles dynamically calling and registering the content types I work with.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your post type before you flush the rules. Your `init` action doesn't run on plugin activation, so your `flush_rewrite` method should call `register_content_types` first before flushing the rules.